# Sum of all Products on Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, products, catalan-numbers

how can I simplify this?

let:
$$
C_n = {{2n \choose n}\over n+1}
$$

find:

$$
\sum_{P_1 + P_2 + ... + P_k = r} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^k C_{P_j}\right)
$$

thanks!

Comment: seriously?! How Dear Marko Riedel and Robert Israel answer this question  if it needs more detail?!!!

Comment: Hello, I would like to know in which context did you faced this problem, just out of curiosity. I just came to the same expression in a crypto related subject!

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik Hi! This question was sent to me by my professor. I it's matter, I can ask him!

Comment: Hi, please do so! Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @RobertIsrael we have the generating function of the Catalan
numbers

$$f(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$

and the quantity in question is

$$[z^r] f(z)^k.$$

This has the integral representation

$$[z^r] f(z)^k
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{r+1}} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^k
\; dz.$$

Now put $1-4z = w^2$ so that $1/4-w^2/4 = z$ and
$dz = -w/2 \; dw$ to get

$$-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{4^{r+k+1}}{(1-w^2)^{r+k+1}}
(1-w)^k w
\; dw
\\ = - 2^{2r+k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{r+1}}
w \; dw
\\ = (-1)^r 2^{2r+k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+1}} \frac{1}{(w-1)^{r+1}}
w \; dw
\\ = (-1)^r 2^{2r+k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+1}} \frac{1}{(w-1)^{r}}
\; dw
\\ +  (-1)^r 2^{2r+k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+1}} \frac{1}{(w-1)^{r+1}}
\; dw.$$

Now we require the derivative

$$\left(\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+1}}\right)^{(q)}
= (-1)^q \frac{(r+k+q)!}{(r+k)!}
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{r+k+q+1}}.$$

This yields for the two pieces

$$(-1)^r 2^{2r+k+1}
(-1)^{r-1} \frac{(2r+k-1)!}{(r-1)!(r+k)!} \frac{1}{2^{2r+k}}
+ (-1)^r 2^{2r+k+1}
(-1)^{r} \frac{(2r+k)!}{r!(r+k)!} \frac{1}{2^{2r+k+1}}
\\ = -2 {2r+k-1\choose r-1}
+ {2r+k\choose r}
\\ = {2r+k\choose r}
\left(1-2\frac{r}{2r+k}\right)
\\ = \frac{k}{2r+k} {2r+k\choose r}.$$

Here we have used the fact that $\sqrt{1-4z} = 1 - 2z - 2z^2 - \cdots$
so that  with $z$  rotating once  around the  origin the  variable $w$
rotates once around the value one, with a contour that may be deformed
to a circle.

Comment: Excellent! but just one thing! would you please explain me how my question mapped into this lovely solution? I mean how finding $$[z^r] f(z)^k$$ is equal to finding the main problem's answer? thanks...

Comment: This is the generalized [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 1):

I presume $k$ is a fixed positive integer.
This will be the coefficient of $x^r$ in $g(x)^k$, where $g(x) =  \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ is the generating function of the Catalan numbers.
According to Maple, it is
$$\frac { (k+2r-1)! \; k}{(k+r)! \; r!}
$$

Comment: oh! after days and days I finally found why "This will be the coefficient of xrxr in g(x)k"!!!