# Products of Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The catalan numbers are extremely well known, with several bijections and a known generating function. But what about products of catalan numbers?

If we define the sequence $P(x) = \prod_{i=0}^x C(i)$, where $C(i)$ is the $i$th Catalan number, are there any special properties of $P(x)$? Does it have any known bijections or a generating function?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003046

Comment: is that all that's known? I had looked at the OEIS originally, but it didn't have anything interesting such as a generating function or bijection.

Comment: There are references to some papers there, they may have more.

Comment: See also [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316953/products-of-catalan-numbers)., showing that the multiple product is never again a Catalan number. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460460/sum-of-product-of-catalan-numbers) for the sum of products of Catalan numbers, or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702416/sum-of-all-products-on-catalan-numbers). And above all, here is the page of an expert on Catalan numbers: [Igor Pak](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/lectures/Cat/pakcat.htm), which has many links.